# Snowflake SQL: Extract from bracketed list of strings

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a particularly hairy string I need to parse using SQL on snowflake. The source data looks like this:

[sample data image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOHVh.png)

I need to extract the default sub brand for each brand ID. For the 3 records shown, the values should be Amazon, Alphabet, and null.

I figure the first step would be to flatten the string into multiple rows per brand (i.e. each set of curly brackets on a different row) but I've tried many combinations of regex/json functions as well as lateral/flatten, but can't seem to figure out the best way to accomplish this.

Here is the code to create a sample table to test out:

```
select 
    column1 as brand_id,
    column2 as sub_brand_data
from values
(1, '"[{\\"Name\\":\\"Amazon\\",\\"CD\\":\\"AMZ\\",\\"IsDefault\\":true}]"'),
(2, '"[{\\"Name\":\\"Google\\",\\"CD\":\\"GOG\\",\\"IsDefault\\":false},{\\"Name\\":\\"Alphabet\\",\\"CD\\":\\"ALP\\",\\"IsDefault\\":true}]"'),
(3, '"[]")')
;

select * from sub_brand_extract
```

*note that the create table statement has extra '' to escape the literal \ in the source string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a bit of cleanup with the `trim` function, and then get rid of the escaping of the double quotes. From there, it's valid JSON (an array) that can be parsed with the `parse_json` function.

From there it's possible to use the `flatten` table function to convert them into rows (if desired).

```
with VALS as
(
select 
    column1 as brand_id,
    column2 as sub_brand_data,
    parse_json(replace(trim(column2, '"())'), '\\"', '"')) as column3
from values
(1, '"[{\\"Name\\":\\"Amazon\\",\\"CD\\":\\"AMZ\\",\\"IsDefault\\":true}]"'),
(2, '"[{\\"Name\":\\"Google\\",\\"CD\":\\"GOG\\",\\"IsDefault\\":false},{\\"Name\\":\\"Alphabet\\",\\"CD\\":\\"ALP\\",\\"IsDefault\\":true}]"'),
(3, '"[]")')
)
select   BRAND_ID
        ,VALUE:CD::string as CD
        ,VALUE:IsDefault::string as IS_DEFAULT
        ,VALUE:Name::string as NAME
from VALS, table(flatten(COLUMN3))
;
```

| BRAND_ID | CD | IS_DEFAULT | NAME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AMZ | true | Amazon |
| 2 | GOG | false | Google |
| 2 | ALP | true | Alphabet |

Comment: Incredible - thank you! This works perfectly. Out of curiosity, why did you include the ()) in the trim function? There were none of those characters in the input, so including them seemingly does nothing. I took them out of that function and the results are the same.

Comment: Row 3 in the sample had an extraneous parenthesis (not JSON specs) `'"[]")'`. The SQL string for a JSON string of a JSON object (that represents an empty array) would be `'"[]"'`. If you don't need to trim extraneous parenthesis in the actual usage, you can remove that.